# Simulator build for Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, xcode-6.2

I want to know if anyone could suggest that how can I create Simulator build for `Apple Watch`.
I'm following the steps in this [link to create simulator build](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/iOS /creating-iOS -simulator-build-for-review)

but if we use command like **`xcodebuild -showsdks`**
It only showing `iPhone Simulator`.

Though I've created simulator build using these command for project having target for `Apple Watch`, but it do not run on watch simulator.

So, it will be helpful if anyone could suggest how to create `Simulator` build for `Apple Watch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your WatchKit app and extension are part of your iPhone app you just need to create simulator build for your iPhone app.  Then when you install your iPhone app in the iPhone simulator it will also install your WatchKit app on the watch.

If you just want to run your app on the Apple Watch from Xcode then you can just select your WatchKit app in the list of schemes and then build & run.  You will need to enable to Apple Watch display as Pablo A. mentions.

Comment: When I'm Lauching the app using [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim), It launches it to iPhone4 Simulator. AFAIK, WatchKit app do not support below iPhone5. Not sure how can I launch it to iPhone5 simulator. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @AmitSingh With ios-sim you can specify the device in the command line with this argument:  --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5,8.3"

Answer (score 1):

Go to the simulator (iOS 8.2 or greater) and

**Hardware - External Displays - Apple Watch**

Comment: I'm asking for simulator build not how to open Apple watch Simulator, its something like creating .app file of the project and later it can be installed to simulator for testing.